# Why can't I use jQuery prop to get the CSS setting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the HTML file, I have created a DOM element:

```
<div id="colorOne"></div>
```

and I set the attributes in css file:

```
#colorOne{
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    left: 8%;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    background-color: white;    
}
```

However, as I command

```
$('#colorOne').prop('width');    $('#colorOne').prop('height');
```

If I want to get any attribute of the element `colorOne` by `$.prop`, it only shows `undefined`. But I also noticed that  if I change `prop` to `css` and I can get what I want.

And if I write

```
<div id="colorOne" style="width:36px;"></div>
```

And the `$.prop` works.

I want to know why is that. How does the browser engine handle these two different writing methods?

(1. inline style 2. setting the attributes in .css file)

Comment: because `.prop` is similar to `.attr` which reads/modify attributes. to read/modify CSS use `.css`. to read attribute use `.attr`.

Comment: this example shows the differences http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vJ3jv/

Comment: @Omar               The example is quite clear, thank you.

Comment: use `.prop` to `disabled` elements and `checked` radio/checkbox. i'll update the example. check the example again http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vJ3jv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the final, computed style with jQuery you need to use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

This uses [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) internally so you can use it with styles from several different sources.

Here is what jQuery does internally to do this:

```
function (elem, name) {
    var ret, defaultView, computedStyle, width, style = elem.style;

    name = name.replace(rupper, "-$1").toLowerCase();

    if ((defaultView = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView) && (computedStyle = defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null))) {

        ret = computedStyle.getPropertyValue(name);
        if (ret === "" && !jQuery.contains(elem.ownerDocument.documentElement, elem)) {
            ret = jQuery.style(elem, name);
        }
    }

    // A tribute to the "awesome hack by Dean Edwards"
    // WebKit uses "computed value (percentage if specified)" instead of "used value" for margins
    // which is against the CSSOM draft spec: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/#resolved-values
    if (!jQuery.support.pixelMargin && computedStyle && rmargin.test(name) && rnumnonpx.test(ret)) {
        width = style.width;
        style.width = ret;
        ret = computedStyle.width;
        style.width = width;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

When you perform a `.attr` or `.prop` call you're reading an HTML attribute/property and *not* a style. If you read the `style` attribute you're only getting *that* and not the actual computed style from all the stylesheets etc.

Comment: So, it's the problem about the jQuery method. I can only get the attributes only if they are inline style?

Comment: @Stallman That's not what I said at all. Attributes _are_ a part of HTML, there are things that are logically attributes. The `src` attribute of a script or the `href` attribute of a link for example. `.attr` simply isn't the right tool in order to get a computed style of an element. (that's what `.css` is for, and it works with inline styles just fine). See http://jsfiddle.net/qKtB5/

Comment: Ok... So, in your coding style, do you usually use `$.css` to configure the attribute of the DOM elements? Or how do you configure the attribute of elements? I mean do you usually set the attribute of elements in css file and configure them by using '$.css' instead of '$.prop' or '$.attr'

Comment: @Stallman I rarely use jQuery in my coding style (It's rare when you work with something like Knockout or AngularJS) :) However, when I do, I set _style_ attributes with `.css` (for example, width, height, etc) and _attributes with `.attr` (like src, href, rel). Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 1):

[`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is what you want.

Try:

```
$('#colorOne').css('width');    
$('#colorOne').css('height');
```

`$.prop` is use to access attributes like `name`, `href`, etc.

If you still want to use `prop`, you will have to set `width`, `height` attributes in html elements.

```
<div id="colorOne" width='36px'></div>
$('#colorOne').prop('width');
```

The above works because, `width` is an attribute to the element `#colorOne`. 
If `width` of the element is changed by js or css(using `!important`) in anyway, `$.prop` will give you wrong answer. But `$.css` will give you the correct one.

Comment: Yes, I did it. I just want to know why is that.